# How can customize the conversion of json to xml?

Tags: json, xml, apache-nifi

I have a JSON object such as `{ name: "Tyler", age: 10, dogName: "Spot", dogAge: "40" }`

Using NiFi, I want to convert it to XMLin a format similar to

```
<person>
  <name>Tyler</tyler>
  <age>10</age>
  <dog>
    <dogName>Spot</dogName>
    <dogAge>40</dogAge>
  </dog>
</person>
```

I am using a ConvertRecord processor. I am using JsonTreeReader for the Record Reader and XMLRecordSetWriter for the Record Writer. I am able to read in the JSON just fine. Is there a way to customize XMLRecordSetWriter to be able to output the xml in a specific format? Right now all I can do is turn the above json object into the following:

```
<name>Tyler</tyler>
<age>10</age>
<dogName>Spot</dogName>
<dogAge>40</dogAge>
```

It just directly converts JSON to XML. Is there a way to customize this? Is there an alternative to XMLRecordSetWriter that I could use?

Comment: Post-process the generated XML using XSLT?

Comment: I agree with mr Kay ... see this Processor ... https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.10.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TransformXml/index.html

Comment: @MichaelKay Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I can first generate the XML and then use XSLT to get it in the correct format that I am looking for.

Comment: @Kolban Thanks, the TransformXML processor should do the trick.

Comment: The json-to-xml() function in XSLT 3.0 was designed on the assumption that you would *always* want to post-process the XML for production use.